# JS: innerHTML causes content to inadvertently change

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have been working on a complex project for the past few weeks when I encountered this bizarre bug. I have since isolated my problem in the code below, which is the smallest possible valid HTML and JS that reproduces it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Chat</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[         
        function refresh()
        {
            var old = document.getElementById("conversation").innerHTML;
            var message = '<img/>';

            if(old != message) {
                alert("Old:\n" + old);
                alert("New:\n" + message);
                //alert("Refreshed!");
                document.getElementById("conversation").innerHTML = message;
            }
        }
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="refresh()">
    <div id="conversation"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">var myVar = setInterval(function(){refresh();},1000);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Every second, the function `refresh()` checks to see if the code in the `div` is different than the stored string. If it is different, it replaces the `div`'s contents with the string. However, each time it checks, it sees the contents and the stored string are different. Although the string is `<img/>`, the `innerHTML` is returned as `<img>`. I figured out that for any self-closing tag, it automatically removes the slash. For a tag that isn't supposed to be self-closing (like `<i>`), it automatically splits it into two tags (like `<i></i>`). For any other tag or text, it does nothing.

I don't really understand why the `div`'s contents are changing at all. If anyone can explain why, I would appreciated it. If someone can even provide a possible solution, I would be grateful.

Comment: The div's contents are changing because the string `<img>` is not equal to the string `<img/>`. Why are you performing string-based equality checks on HTML instead of proper DOM manipulation in the first place?

Comment: Thank you all for the help. The entire program takes strings that can contain HTML markup from a server and put them in the `div`. It only updates if it detects a difference between the current string and the previous string. I would like to avoid using something as complicated as DOM manipulation when I am only trying to compare strings. Your information about the impossibility of that led me to a different solution: storing `old` as a static variable to remove the need to read from the document itself. Thank you yet again.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the browser is using an HTML parser, not an XML parser for the page, that's why it will remove the closing slash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a relative novice myself but I think what Matt Ball is referring to is the fact that you are creating a string when you should be creating a new DOM element So one simple change to your function would be:

```
var convo = document.getElementById("conversation");

function refresh() {
    var old = convo.innerHTML;
    var message = document.createElement("IMG");
    if (old != message) {
        alert("Old:\n" + old);
        alert("New:\n" + message);
        //alert("Refreshed!");
        convo.innerHTML = message;
    }

}
```

Here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/YTH4t/1/)

Note: I added the global `convo` variable to reduce keystrokes and use `document.createElemet` instead of `innerHTML` to add the new image element to the DOM.  You can then call upon that image element inside or outside your function using the `firstChild` method like this:

```
convo.firstChild;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the use of `convo.innerHTML = message;` in the last line of the if statement will display the string that results from the browser parsing `document.createElement("IMG")` not a literal string that reads `<img>`.  Perhaps a better method would be to use `convo.appendChild(message)` but then you'd have to restructure your code so your `setInterval` function didn't cause it to append a new child every second.